# Show curl output from ant

Tags: java, curl, ant, testflight

I have an `ant` build script that among other stuff uploads a file to the server. Here is a code from my `build.xml` I am talking about:

```
<target name="-upload_to_testflight">
    <echo>Uploading APP.ipa to TestFlight.com</echo>
    <exec executable="cat" outputproperty="msg">
        <arg value="./build/testflight.txt"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="curl" failonerror="true" dir="${basedir}">
        <arg value="http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json"/>
        <arg value="-F file=@out-build/APP.ipa"/>
        <arg value="-F api_token=${testflight.api.token}"/>
        <arg value="-F team_token=${testflight.team.token}"/>
        <arg value="-F notes=${msg}"/>
        <arg value="-F notify=True"/>
        <arg value="-F distribution_lists=APP"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

My problem is that `ant` doesn't show `curl` uploading progress. If I run `curl` in `Terminal.app` I see uploading progress. When `curl` task is done `ant` shows all output from `curl` at once which is not useful.

It looks like progress output from `curl` is buffered by `ant` until `curl` is finished.

Is there a technique that let me see `curl` output immediately?

ADDED:

I discovered some technique that might be a solution:

```
$script -q /dev/null curl --progress-bar http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso -o ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso | tr $'\r' $'\n' | tr -d ' ' > /dev/tty
```

Comment: If there is not need to collect the curl output, then try to use the spawn="true" attribute. It decouples ant and curl. May be worth a try.